# Почему некотрые android приложения так быстро запускаются?

Tags: android, оптимизация

Приложение, которое генерирует Android Stuido если выбрать шаблон "Empty activity" запускается за 850-950 мс:

```
2021-07-20 21:28:17.750 1321-1344/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.tutaf.emptyapp/.MainActivity: +956ms
```

Для сравнения:

- Telegram X: 400-500 мс
- Firefox: 550-1000 мс
- VLC: 700-900 мс
- 4PDA: 400-600 мс
- Total Commander: 600-800 мс

Если перед проверкой очистить кэш и остановить приложение, то Firefox и VLC запускаются медленнее пустого приложения, однако Telegram X, 4PDA и Total Commander запускаются либо за то же время, либо быстрее. Почему эти приложения запускаются быстрее и как можно приблизиться к их результату?

Comment: А вы релизную сборку запускаете или дебажную?

Comment: @IR42, да, дело было в дебажной сборке, спасибо. Напишите ответ, отмечу решением